# VB6 MS access driver connection string using label or variable

Tags: vb6

by default MS access connection string is

```
connection = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
    "dbq=Database1.mdb;" & _
    "DefaultDir=E:\somepath;" & _
    "uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
```

and i want use label to get database path info

```
connection = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
    Chr(34) & "dbq=" & lblF.Caption & ";" & Chr(34) & _
    Chr(34) & "DefaultDir=" & LocL.Caption & ";" & Chr(34) & _
    "uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
```

but it's fail :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the Chr() calls. You don't need to insert any double quotes in this connection string.

i.e.

```
connection = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
             "dbq=" & lblF.Caption & ";" & _
             "DefaultDir=" & LocL.Caption & ";" & _
             "uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
```